# org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles - after installing ibus

Tags: linux, eclipse

I needed to install ibus on Ubuntu 19.04 LTS and shortly after doing so I started getting this error when trying any file in Eclipse 2019.

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

I tried installing the newest version thinking something broke in Eclipse, but I couldn't even install because I got the same error in the installer.

I didn't realize right away that ibus was the cause because I didn't try using Eclipse for several hours after installing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying just about everything, the answer turned out to be the need to set the GTK mode before launching Eclipse.

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
```

To make my life easier in the future, I created a script file to do this any time I started Eclipse. This is a simple text file with the executable flag set.

```
#/bin/bash

export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"
~/Programs/eclipse/php-2019-03/eclipse/eclipse
```

I hope this saves others a great deal of searching.

Comment: It works flawlessly! But the side effect is that it doesn't allow typing Chinese in Eclipse. Not that I need that, but it prevents me from even trying. So it looks that there's a trade off.